# What plant can this be?

Tags: identification, flowers, flowering, outdoor

This plant is flowering now in winter season, I don't know whether it will bloom in the summers. This is the flower.[image]

This is its bud. [image]

This is the plant itself.[image]

Local vendor said it is [Aster](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=white%20aster&client=ubuntu&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6_ZTCu6ruAhWa7nMBHeBGBPcQiR56BAg-EAI&biw=1319&bih=670), but I don't think so after Googling. What can it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a dianthus; its wide green leaves indicate that it's probably a cultivar of *Dianthus chinensis*. These plants like cool weather and usually bloom in the spring in my area of the US - looks like you're living in a region with a mild winter, which means it will be a (possibly short-lived) perennial where you live. The flowers may smell sweetly of cloves.